# Invoke Java program in Linux using "./"

Tags: java, linux

Is it possible to invoke a Java program in a Linux command line using a command like "./hello"?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you could have a look at `binfmt_misc`, which probably has some supporting packages within your distro, eg `binfmt-support` for debian.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a script called `hello`, chmod it into executable, place it on a folder registered on your PATH environment variable, for example:

```
$ echo '$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar /path/to/myjar.jar' > hello
$ chmod a+x hello
$ ./hello
```